# Managing data from http method in controller with AngularJS 1.5 components

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, components, angularjs-http

Ng-repeat in component can't show data charged from $http.then in controller. What am i doing wrong?

Service calling rest method in app.js:

```
    app.service('dataService', dataService);

    function dataService ($http) {

    return {
     loadData: loadData
    }        

    function loadData() {

      var promise = $http.get("http://example.com/channels").then(function (response) {

        res = response.data;

      });
      return promise;

    }
```

Loading data in component.js

```
function channelListController(dataService){

this.channels = [];
/** If i create var like this, this works, but i want load from http method:
 this.channels = [{id:1, name: "xxxxx", description: "xxxxxxx", sport:    "xxxx"}]**/

dataService.loadData().then(function(d) {

  console.log(d);  //This console.log is showing DATA correctly!
  this.channels = d; 
});
```

Trying to showing data in view:

```
<tr ng-repeat="channel in $ctrl.channels">
        <td>{{ channel.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ channel.sport }}</td>
(...)
```

(Deploying with http-server)

The channels are not showing in view. If i create a var with data named channels, in channelListController before catch http.method, channels are showing OK, but if i charge data into the ".then" in controller, i cant show anything. The trace get into .then, and the http get method is receiving data correctly, but i can't load data into 'channels' var.

THANKS!!

Comment: If you insist on using `this.channels` inside the callback you pass to `then`, you should bind that entire callback to `this` to make sure you're updating the correct variable (i.e. `(function (d) { this.channels = d; }).bind(this)`). Otherwise, `this.channels` is not updating the `channels` variable you expect it to be.

Comment: @miqid thanks, it's working!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your references are wrong. Following should fix it

```
function channelListController(dataService){

var that = this;
this.channels = [];
/** If i create var like this, this works, but i want load from http method:
 this.channels = [{id:1, name: "xxxxx", description: "xxxxxxx", sport:    "xxxx"}]**/

dataService.loadData().then(function(d) {

  console.log(d);  //This console.log is showing DATA correctly!
  that.channels = d; // use that instead of this
});
```